# Retrieve data from Future<Directory> function

Tags: flutter, dart

so basically I would like to retrieve a Directory from a path_provider function called getTemporaryDirectory() and I am facing a problem with returning data type from a function called getDir() which should return a type Directory variable but instead returns a type dynamic.

```dart
Directory tempDir;

Future<Directory> dire() async {
  Directory dire = await getTemporaryDirectory(); //!temporary directory 
  return dire;
}
getDir() async {
  Directory dir = await dire();
  return dir;
}

@override
  void initState() {
    tempDir = getDir();
  }
```

The error I am getting is:
type 'Future(dynamic)' is not a subtype of type 'Directory'

Comment: why do you need both `dire` and `getDir` methods if they return the same thing? if you want to get the data from completed `Future` use its `then()` method and you will be able to list the files for example

Answer (score 0):

you may want to consider

```dart
Directory dir = (await dire()) as Directory;
```

note: my knowledge of Dart is heavily outdated and maybe i shouldn't be answering questions about it on SO

Answer (score 0):

You better specify a return type for getDir:

```dart
Future<Directory> getDir() async {
```

And you can't await a value inside *initState*, so you have to use a callback:

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getDir().then((v) {
      setState(() {
        tempDir = v;
      });
    });
  }
```